# Hide button and display redirect text

Tags: html, forms

I have this simple submit form which I send to user's browser from Spring Endpoint:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no cache" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no cache" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0" />
   </head>
   <body OnLoad="AutoSubmitForm();">
      <form name="downloadForm" action="AcsUrl" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="PaReq" />
         <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="TermUrl" />
         <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="optionalValue" />
         <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
            AutoSubmitForm() { document.downloadForm.submit();}
         </SCRIPT>
         <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there some way to hide the `continue` button and display "Redirecting" when the page is run the client's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your script to:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
   AutoSubmitForm() { 
     document.downloadForm.submit();
   }
  var form = document.querySelector('form[name="downloadForm"]');
  var submitFN = function () {
     // hide btn
     document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').style.display = "none";
     // create dom node let it be paragraph
     var node = document.createElement("p"); 
     // create text node 'redirecting'
     var textnode = document.createTextNode("Redirecting");     
     // append text node to dom node 
     node.appendChild(textnode);
     // append dom node to dom body
     document.querySelector("body").appendChild(node); 
  }
  form.addEventListener("submit", submitFN, false);
</SCRIPT>
```

Without JS:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no cache" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no cache" />
      <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0" />
   </head>
   <body OnLoad="AutoSubmitForm();">
      <form name="downloadForm" action="AcsUrl" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="PaReq" />
         <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="TermUrl" />
         <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="optionalValue" />
         <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
            AutoSubmitForm() { document.downloadForm.submit();}
         </SCRIPT>
         <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue" style="display: none;"/>
      </form>
      <p> Redirecting</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for some reason the button is only displayed. The form is not submitted

Comment: edited, I changed  code so it's triggered after submit, try it now

Comment: Just in case to ask. Is there some way to make it without JavaScript? Because it might be disabled into web browser?

Comment: I am not sure what you are up to, if JavaScript would be disabled the form, couldn't be submited, but I will edit my answer and add just html code where you go on page and have hidden submit btn and render paragraph, without extra js

Comment: Checkout Without JS version if it works it seems much easier, but if you turn off JS in browser auto submit won't run and you could be stucked, but it really rarely happens in nowadays, that ppl have turned off js in web browsers, cheers

Comment: thanks. In general is there some other way to auto submit the form without JS?